# AlertDialog setSingleChoice without radio buttons

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I am using an alertDialog to display data similar to a spinner.  Is there a way to move the active selection (like in setSingleChoice) using setItems ?

I want the displayed list to look like a spinner, without the radio buttons.

Answer (score 12):

Check out [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog) from the Android API. You can create a list of items to display. The array length can be as long as you want. The list will scroll when the number of items gets big enough. Very much like a spinner.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: seems setItems() only accepts string array